# externalInterface javascript not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

In my website I use externalInterface for communication between my javascript code and my flash games.

this works great on IE 10 but does not work on IE 11.

sample code:

```
 if (ie) {
            console.log('sending the graphs data');
            console.log("result_graph_object: " +     document.getElementById("result_graph_object"));
            console.log("is function: " + (typeof document.getElementById("result_graph_object").setGraphPath == 'function'));
            window.document.getElementById("result_graph_object").setGraphPath(handpath);  
        }
```

console output in IE10:

```
sending the graphs data 
result_graph_object: [object HTMLObjectElement]  
is function: true
```

console output in IE11:

```
sending the graphs data 
result_graph_object: [object HTMLObjectElement]  
is function: false
```

for some reason IE11 does not recognize the flash object method ("is function: false" on IE11).

does anyone have any idea why this happens?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whom this may concern,

IE 11 works with flash embed elements just like google chrome,
and not with flash object elements like in previous IE versions...

that was the solution to my issue