# SCORM (flash Player Content) not working on Windows Server 2012 R2 which has IE11 integrated installed on it

Tags: asp.net, flash, internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012-r2, scorm1.2

I have website which contains SCORM package, installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 which has IE11 installed on it. Flash Player is also embedded with IE.

IE Version:  11.0.9600.17278.

Updated Version: 11.0.12 (KB2977629)

When I launch SCORM (flash Player Content) from my application, it is not working. It just displays a blank page however the Title of IE is set to the text from the SCORM content.

However if I access the same URL from any other machine which has previous version of Windows OS (i.e. previous to Windows 8 OS), it is working as expected on IE9, IE10 and IE11.

While trying to find out the cause, I came across some forum which says we have to install the “Desktop Experience” on the server to enable the inbuilt flash player. After doing that also, My SCORM contents are not getting displayed.

To find out more details, I have uploaded the SCORM Package on SCORM Cloud to check if it is working there. Here again the same problem, it doesn’t work and displays error message saying that “Member is not found” and when I tried to find out the location of the error then it is coming at windows.document.myflash.SetVariable(…) method on the Windows Server 2012 R2 with IE11.

When I performed “Addwatch”, it is saying that windows.document.myflash doesn’t have SetVariable(…) method.

However if access the same cloud URL from other machine (Having OS previous to Windows 8 OS), it is working as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See related ExternalInterface issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478690/why-flash-call-external-interface-not-longer-called-in-ie11 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994078/externalinterface-javascript-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause and the solution for the same.

Actually it was throwing an javascript error which was expecting "StudentName" and "StudentID" property which I haven't set. However even though I was not setting these parameter, it was working on other versions of IE.

After setting these parameters, it is working now.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server has probably a restricted Internet Explorer installed (this is an addon for IE that restricts the kind of content that can be run from a web page).
If this is disabling flash content, you will have to uninstall the addon.

You could check if any other flash based page is working, e.g. Youtube to confirm that Flash is disabled.

Comment: I have checked the YouTube and it is working which means there is no issue with flash. There is a javascript error coming when I uploaded my content on SCORM Cloud at windows.document.myflash.SetVariable(..). It says that myflash doesn't have SetVariable (...) method. I am not able to uninstall the Flash add on.

Comment: Youtube also works without flash (html5 player), be sure to verify that it is really running the flash player. If you have the restriction addon installed, you have to deinstall that, not the flash addon

Comment: I checked the youTube after disabling the Flash Add on. It is not working. Even if I enable the Flash Add on then also it is not playing the flash content however it is only showing a blank page. There is only one Add on which is flash player. Since flash player is integrated with IE, it is not allowing to uninstall. Hence I am not able to install Flash player separately.

Comment: then I'm all out of ideas